# fit ImageView into listView

Tags: android, listview, imageview

I searched for an answer to my problem but i couldn't find one that goes with my situation.. So my application is an online shop for computers. I made two listViews and two custom rows.. one for the Shop and one for the basket. They both display some features of the product and it's picture in the right. My problem is my pictures (they are taken directly from the server) cannot fit correctly in my ImageViews and ListViews and i'm looking for a solution. Thank you in advance

**Ps :** i'm using Picasso library to display the picture.
the used Picasso line of code :

```
Picasso.with(this.getContext()).load(lFoto).into(foto);
```

**custom_row_shop.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_ref"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Ref Artikel :"
            android:textColor="#2383c4"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Betriebssytem :"
            android:textSize="9sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_betriebssystem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="sldjq"
            android:textSize="9sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Prozessor :"
            android:textSize="9sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_prozessor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="sldjq"
            android:textSize="9sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Grafikkarte :"
            android:textSize="9sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_grafikkarte"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="sldjq"
            android:textSize="9sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="RAM :"
            android:textSize="9sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_arbeitsspeicher"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="sldjq"
            android:textSize="9sp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Festplatte :"
            android:textSize="9sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_festplatte"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="sldjq"
            android:textSize="9sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/list_foto"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**custom_row_basket.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_warenKorb_ref"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Ref Artikel :"
            android:textColor="#2383c4"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Menge :"
            android:textSize="9sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_warenKorb_menge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="sldjq"
            android:textSize="9sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="Preis :"
            android:textSize="9sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_warenKorb_preis"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="sldjq"
            android:textSize="9sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/list_warenKorb_foto"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Shop]

[image: Basket]

Comment: Your ImageView in the right is cut off. Do you want fit the ImageView to right?

Comment: @RoShanShan yes and i want it still so that it dosen't go back and forth like the second picture shows. the laptop reference of the second item (in blue) is shorter than the first one ! that's why the picture is too close to the left ! i want it always fixed in the right side

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `RelativeLayout`, try the layout below, the image fit the right, not cut off
**custom_row_shop.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/list_foto"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list_ref"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="Ref Artikel :"
                android:textColor="#2383c4"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="Betriebssytem :"
                android:textSize="9sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list_betriebssystem"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="sldjq"
                android:textSize="9sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="Prozessor :"
                android:textSize="9sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />



          <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/list_prozessor"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:text="sldjq"
                    android:textSize="9sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:text="Grafikkarte :"
                    android:textSize="9sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/list_grafikkarte"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:text="sldjq"
                    android:textSize="9sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:text="RAM :"
                    android:textSize="9sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/list_arbeitsspeicher"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:text="sldjq"
                    android:textSize="9sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:text="Festplatte :"
                    android:textSize="9sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/list_festplatte"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:text="sldjq"
                    android:textSize="9sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_foto"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**custom_row_basket.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/list_warenKorb_foto"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list_warenKorb_ref"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="Ref Artikel :"
                android:textColor="#2383c4"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="Menge :"
                android:textSize="9sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list_warenKorb_menge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="sldjq"
                android:textSize="9sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="Preis :"
                android:textSize="9sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list_warenKorb_preis"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="sldjq"
                android:textSize="9sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_warenKorb_foto"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the issue that your images are sometimes pushed to far to the right?  That is what it looks like to me but not sure.  If so try temporarily putting some background colors on the TextViews to see if they are taking up too much space.

Comment: the text takes too much space ! any tips how to avoid that ? and as you can see the pictures dosen't fit in the ImageView ! there is some cuts.. how can i display them properly inside the ImageView. Also in the second picture the second item reference (in blue) is much shorter than the first one ! that's why the first picture dosen't show up ! but the second picture is too much close to the left ! how can i set the imageview to a still place so it dosen't go back and forth ! i hope i was clear enough

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Use android:scaleType="fitXY"

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/list_foto"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />
```

Java class:

```
    Picasso.with(this.getContext()).load(lFoto).into(foto);
```